# Can I get a Logger by specifying a file that contains a log4net configuration?

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

For example, like

```
LogManager.GetLogger("C:\myloggerconfig.xml", "MyLoggerName");
```

Comment: No. That would seem unnecessarily complicated. Can you explian what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't see why someone would downvote this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to drop the following code into your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="c:\\myloggerconfig.xml",Watch=true)]
```

You can also do it programatically:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("c:\\myloggerconfig.xml");
```

Comment: and from that moment my assembly will always use that configuration?